# Error: "Channel not in Stasis application" when adding channel to a bridge

Tags: voip, asterisk

I'm working with Asterisk ARI. When I create channels via ARI, I specify application name and I can add those channels to a bridge with no problem. But when I use other client (like Zoiper) to make calls, and try to add those channels to a bridge, I get an error "Channel not in Stasis application". I am not sure what is Stasis, I followed [this article](http://astrecipes.net/index.php?q=astrecipes/getting%20started%20with%20ari) and put the following in extensions conf file, but it still doesn't work:

```
same => n,Stasis(myApp)
same => n,Hangup()
```

So, what is a stasis app and how can I be able to bridge channels which are created outside of ARI?